# google analytics mobile app tracking, regarding counting real new visitors

Tags: mobile, google-analytics, usertype, user-tracking

What if i delete the app, and re install it.

Does GA count me as new visitor ? or returning visitor?

and plus, how does GA tell whether a visitor is new or returning in mobile app?

does it detects visitors device ID? or mac address?

(I found that GA knows UV by its MAC address but not for sure with new & returning visitors)

as far as i know, since MAC addresses are following the device (which means it's not going to change), so that this will be counted as returning?

Please share comments or experiences that you have been encountered so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unique cid (Client ID) is created when you run your app after installation and all the data that Google Analytics collects is linked with it. When you reinstall app, new CID is created.

So, after reinstalling an app GA would count you as new user.

Comment: it's so helpful, appreciate that :-)